# Editing a String without Python Commands (with "for i in range")

Tags: python, python-2.7

For an assignment, I need code that asks the user for a word and a letter. Then, it edits the word to not include the specific letter. It needs in include a "for i in range" statement. The code before works but doesn't use a for loop and uses a python command.

```
word1 = raw_input ("Give me a word! ")
letter1 = raw_input ("Give me a letter! ")
modify = word1.replace(letter1,"")
check = word1.find(letter1)
if check == -1:
     print "There is no letters to replace in", word1
     check = 0
if check >= 1:
     print modify
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
word = raw_input('Give me a word! ')
letter = raw_input('Give me a letter! ')
cleaned = ''
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] != letter:
        cleaned += word[i]
if cleaned:
    print cleaned
else:
    print 'There is no letters to replace in', word
```

Comment: you should get something for doing his homework.. ha! :-p

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a string letter by letter like you would a list or dict

```
word='someword'
for letter in word:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I am not very experienced with python. I don't know what a list or dict is.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: list and dict are just python types. A list is a mutable array and a dict more closely resembles an associative array.  Would be good to check the docs on python types as it can enlighten you more on the language. https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html

Comment: @JohnTrevor this site is not meant to be a beginner's guide. You should get comfortable with Basic Python before posting here.

Comment: This answer is worth no more than a comment, considering its size and completeness

Comment: @EliKorvigo if what I posted offends you, you really need to lighten up

Comment: It does not offend me. I've down-voted your answer and provided an explanation for my decision, so that you could improve your answer.